# How do I bind a GridViewComboBoxColumn to multiple fields?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, telerik

My GridViewComboBox ItemsSource is an observable collection of Contacts. It displays both FullName and PhoneExtension in two columns. The combobox is a column in my Telerik WPF RadGridView. The GridViewComboBoxColumn (not working) xaml looks like this:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Name="contactsComboBox"  Header="Contact"
   DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
   SelectedValueMemberPath="FullName"
   ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListObservable}"
   DataMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneExtension}" >

    <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="    Phone: "  Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PhoneExtension}"  Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```

I'd like to bind both FullName and PhoneExtension but it seems I can only have one field in the DataMemberBinding. I'm not sure what belongs in DisplayMemberPath or SelectedValueMemberPath.

I'm also willing to use an event instead of binding. If you can show both the AddHandler and the code for the combobox's SelectionChangedEvent it would be much appreciated.

**How can I bind my multi-column GridViewComboBox to more than one field?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem (I'm answering my own question).

First here are the Multibinding TypeConverters I used:

```
public class CombineFullNameAndPhoneExtensionMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] as string != null)
        {
            string fullName = (string)values[0] ?? "Unknown";
            string phoneExtension = (string)values[1] ?? "Unknown";
            string namePlusExtension = fullName.Trim() + "    Phone: " + phoneExtension.Trim();
            return namePlusExtension;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
                                Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        NotesContact c = (NotesContact)value;

        string[] returnValues = { c.FullName.Trim(), c.PhoneExtension.Trim() };
        return returnValues;
    }
}

public class CombineLastNameFirstNameAndPhoneExtensionMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values,
                         Type targetType,
                         object parameter,
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       if (values[0] as string != null)
       {
           string lastName = (string)values[0] ?? "Unknown";
           string firstName = (string)values[1] ?? "Unknown";
           string phoneExtension = (string)values[2] ?? "Unknown";

           string lastCommaFirstPlusExtension = lastName.Trim() + ", " + firstName.Trim() + "    Phone: " + phoneExtension.Trim();
           return lastCommaFirstPlusExtension;
       }
       return null;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
                               Type[] targetTypes,
                               object parameter,
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Here are the Converter declarations in xaml:

```
<local:CombineFullNameAndPhoneExtensionMultiConverter x:Key="combinedFullNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter"/>
<local:CombineLastNameFirstNameAndPhoneExtensionMultiConverter x:Key="combinedLastNameFirstNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter"/>
```

Now here is the ComboBox xaml:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Name="contactsGridViewComboBox"  Header="Contact"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListObservable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource combinedFullNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="FullName"/>
                        <Binding Path="PhoneExtension"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellEditTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ContactsCellEditTemplate">
        <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=ContactsTemplateComboBox}">
            <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="ContactsTemplateComboBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListObservable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"  IsDropDownOpen="True" TextSearchMode="Contains" IsFilteringEnabled="True" OpenDropDownOnFocus="True">
                <telerik:RadComboBox.SelectedItem>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource combinedFullNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="FullName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        <Binding Path="PhoneExtension" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </telerik:RadComboBox.SelectedItem>
                <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock.Text>                                                        
                                <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource combinedLastNameFirstNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter}">                             
                                    <Binding Path="LastName"/>                                                                                                                                                             <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                    <Binding Path="PhoneExtension"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellEditTemplate>
```

Notice I've made use of **Multibinding**, **CellTemplate** (gets or sets the data template for the cell in view mode) and **CellEditTemplate** (gets or sets the data template for the cell in edit mode). Since I've run out of time I'm letting the code speak for itself. Please leave a comment if you need some clarification or post a new Stack Overflow question if this is too confusing. I have great appreciation for the SO community. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Hi one way to do that is overriding ToString() method and another is using Converter.

```
    public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "abc", RollNo = 1, Course = "MCA" });
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "xyz", RollNo = 1, Course = "MCA" });
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "pqr", RollNo = 1, Course = "MCA" });
        Students.Add(new Student() { Name = "stu", RollNo = 1, Course = "MCA" });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public  class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Course  { get; set; }
    public int RollNo { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name + "  " + this.Course;
    }
}

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"/>
```

another way is using Converter like

```
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (value is Student)
            return ((Student)value).Name + "  " + ((Student)value).Course;
        else
            return null;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: I want the binding to be Two-Way. Name and Phone are saved to separate database fields. So in the converter would I need ConvertBack code?

Comment: You can easily extract them fom your Selected Item , I dnt think there will be any need to Convert back.

Comment: How do I write the GridViewComboBox binding statements so that when the user selects a Contact it binds to both the FullName and PhoneExtension fields?

Comment: I think FullName and PhoneExtension fields belong to the same class and it is the collection of this class that is binded to ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

I think using MultiBinding with a MultiValueConverter should do the trick for you. Refer to the example on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)

The example shows how to bind the text property to a value calculated from 2 bound properties FirstName & LastName

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn  
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}"
                  ConverterParameter="FormatLastFirst">
         <Binding Path="FullName"/>
         <Binding Path="PhoneExt"/>
      </MultiBinding>  
   </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
```

DisplayMemberBinding seems like what you want the combo box drop down to display. DataMemberBinding is what you'd like to get/set back to the store. e.g. you can show 'Phone Number, Ext' to the user but on selection change, only the PhoneExt value would be modified.

Comment: Thanks. I think you have a typo...there is no DisplayMemberBinding property. When I changed it to DataMemberBinding I got this exception: MultiBinding is not allowed for DataMemberBinding because it's not a dependency property. I'll try using MultiBinding on the property DisplayMemberPath. I'll also study your link.

Comment: @DeveloperDan - yeah i was guessing there - don't work with telerik control much. I was just hoping for symmetry.